# program getting stopped after writing byte array to file in dotnet core

Tags: asp.net, .net, .net-core, itext

i am trying to make a pdf from html and store it in local drive, i am hitting this function with an api but just after hitting the api app shuts down, after debugging i found out this is  because of this  `File.WriteAllBytes(@"./2.pdf", bPDF);` part of my code, i didn't find anything wrong with this line, please suggest what i am doing wrong?

Note: this function works perfectly in debug mode.

```
public static void htmlTopdf(){

    try{

        byte[] bPDF = null;

        string pHTML = "<h1>Hello world</h1>";

        MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream();
        TextReader txtReader = new StringReader(pHTML);

        // 1: create object of a itextsharp document class
        Document doc = new Document(PageSize.A4, 25, 25, 25, 25);

        // 2: we create a itextsharp pdfwriter that listens to the document and directs a XML-stream to a file
        PdfWriter oPdfWriter = PdfWriter.GetInstance(doc, ms);

        // 3: we create a worker parse the document
        HTMLWorker htmlWorker = new HTMLWorker(doc);

        // 4: we open document and start the worker on the document
        doc.Open();
        htmlWorker.StartDocument();

        // 5: parse the html into the document
        htmlWorker.Parse(txtReader);

        // 6: close the document and the worker
        htmlWorker.EndDocument();
        htmlWorker.Close();
        doc.Close();
        bPDF = ms.ToArray();
        File.WriteAllBytes(@"./2.pdf", bPDF);

    }catch(Exception ex){
        Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
    }

}
```

Comment: Well, you're catching any exceptions and just writing them to the console - do you have access to that console output? My guess is that the current directory of the process isn't what you expect it to be, and that the process doesn't have write access to that directory... but the first thing you should really look at is making sure you can see any exceptions.

Comment: yes i have,also  i forget to mention above program works in debug mode but not in normal

Comment: "yes i have" - yes you have what, precisely? Access to the console output? If so, what's there? It doesn't help that you've told us very little about how this code is running...

Comment: @sonugupta Check your directory permissions. Your process may run as a user with or without premissions to write to that directory